# rails_admin Enumeration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-admin

I'm new to rails_admin gem. I want to make `:style` field in rails_admin like a dropdown list of options, not like ordinary input fields.
Here is my migration:

```
    class CreatePhones < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
         create_table :phones do |t|
            t.string :audio
            t.string :video
            t.string :style

            t.timestamps
         end
      end
    end
```

And here is my Phone.rb model:

```
    class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
        def style_enum
            ["Free", "Basic", "Advanced", "Super Platinum"] 
        end
    end
```

I read about enumeration and drop-down lists in railsadmin in [documentaion](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Enumeration) and in [this](http://thehungrycoder.com/ruby-on-rails/showing-drop-down-list-box-for-a-field-in-railsadmin.html) manual but nothing seems to work.

I'm getting this error:

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Try `[["Free"], ["Basic"], ["Advanced"], ["Super Platinum"]]` in your `style_enum` method.

Comment: You have everything set up correctly.  The error message is saying you have a syntax error in your style_enum method.  Is there anything funky going on like an extra quotation mark? You could also try using symbols instead of strings and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @vinodadhikary Ok, I tried that, end got the same error.

Comment: @Josh Ok, i tried `[["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"]]` and got the same error. I checked the code for extra quotation marks twice and copy-pasted it here (so you can check it with me :) )
This error is killing me)

Comment: @Josh @vinodadhikary Should I change `/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add this block inside your Phone model:

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  rails_admin do
    field :style, :enum do
      enum do
        %w(a b c d)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this using https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  extend Enumerize
  enumerize :style, in: ['style1', 'style']
...
```

This will create a RA dropdown with those values and enforce enumeration.

Doing `field :style, :enum do` is useful when you have more dynamically restrict values.  You can do `bindings[:object]` and query DB for the values.